# How can i apply offset to UTC time based on the browser time zone .?

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am having an angular 5 project. I am having UTC date and I am trying to print it in the local browser timezone. I am using momentjs libraries. However I find that my code is not applying the offset to the UTC timezone. Really appreciate if you can help.
My project is available in stackblitz

https://angular-wtj1rj.stackblitz.io/

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtj1rj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

In the app.component.ts this is the conversion function i am using

```
 print( item:HistogramDistribution ) {
    return " UTC time: " + item.dateRange + " Local time: " + moment.utc(item.dateRange).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
  }
```

However this prints

```
UTC time: 2020-07-01T13:00:00.000+0000 Local time: 2020-07-01T13:00:00
```

I would expect the result as follows because I am one hour ahead of the UTC timezone.
my timezone is Irish ( GMT+1 )..

```
UTC time: 2020-07-01T13:00:00.000+0000 Local time: 2020-07-01T14:00:00
```

really appreciate if you can help
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `moment.utc(...)` the resulting moment is flagged as UTC - subsequent method calls on it (e.g. `format`) will treat it as UTC and format it accordingly.

If you want it in local time you can call `local()` on it. It still represents the same moment in time, but subsequent calls to `format` etc. will then treat it as local time.

In your example, this will give you the output you want:

```
moment.utc(item.dateRange).local().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
```

[Updated example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-en2stz?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Docs at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/